# Template Class data type

Tags: c++

I've created this pretty simple dynamic list which is implemented with a template class:

Node.h

```
template <class T> class Node
{
public:
    typedef T data_type;
    typedef T& reference_type;

    void setData(data_type);
    void setNextNull();
    void setNext(Node*);

    reference_type getData();
    Node* getNext();

private:
    data_type data;
    Node* next;
};

template <class T> void Node<T>::setData(data_type _data)
{
    data=_data;
}

template <class T> void Node<T>::setNextNull()
{
    next=NULL;
}

template <class T> void Node<T>::setNext(Node* _next)
{
    next=_next;
}

template <class T> typename Node<T>::reference_type Node<T>::getData()
{
    return data;
}

template <class T> typename Node<T>::Node* Node<T>::getNext()
{
    return next;
}
```

List.h

```
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H

#include <Node.h>

template <class T> class List
{
public:
    typedef Node<T> node_type;
    typedef node_type* node_pointer;
    typedef T data_type;
    typedef T& reference_type;

    List();
    void push_back(data_type);
    reference_type at(int);
    void clear();
    void swap(int,int);
    int size();

private:
    int list_size = 0;
    node_pointer head, tail;
};

template <class T> List<T>::List()
{
    head=NULL;
}

template <class T> void List<T>::push_back(data_type data)
{
    if(head == NULL) {
        head = new node_type;
        head->setData(data);
        tail = head;
    } else {
        node_pointer temp = new node_type;
        temp->setData(data);
        temp->setNextNull();
        tail->setNext(temp);
        tail = tail->getNext();
    }
    list_size++;
}

template <class T> typename List<T>::reference_type List<T>::at(int x)
{
    node_pointer pointer=head;
    for(int i=0; i<x; i++)
        pointer=pointer->getNext();

    return pointer->getData();
}

template <class T> void List<T>::clear()
{
    node_pointer pointer = head;
    for(int i=0; i<list_size; i++) {
        node_pointer temp = pointer;
        pointer=pointer->getNext();
        delete(temp);
    }
    head=NULL;
    list_size=0;
}

template <class T> void List<T>::swap(int x, int y)
{
    data_type buffer=at(x);
    at(x)=at(y);
    at(y)=buffer;
}

template <class T> int List<T>::size()
{
    return list_size;
}

#endif // LIST_H
```

The list works perfectly with any form of data type, except when i use a class with a parameter inside it's constructor, then I get this error:

> include/Node.h error: no matching function for call to ‘Player::Player()’

What am I doing wrong??

UPDATE 1

I've added a simple constructor as suggested but I get the same error

```
template <class T> Node<T>::Node(data_type _data)
{
    data=_data;
}
```

Comment: You have to use initializer-list instead of affectation. ( `: my_member(initialValue)`)

Comment: You should add your constructor to your `Player` class. Not your `Node` class. This is the reason you get the error.

Answer (score 1):

You probably haven't defined a default constructor for your `Player` class. Just insert an empty constructor

```
Player() {}
```

And your problem will likely to be solved.

When you write a template method and use it in the main function like this:

```
Node<Player>
```

The compiler automatically calls the constructor of the `Player` class.
If you didn't define any constructors in `Player`, the compiler will use default constructor. However, any constructor you defined will hide the default one and force you to use this one.

For instance, a constructor like

```
Player(string, int, int)
```

Prevents you to create an object like this:

```
Player *p = new Player();
```

However, if you haven't written the constructor, the piece of code above would've worked just fine.

That's why your template needs a default constructor, **iff** you defined a parameterized constructor.

Comment: Works!!! Thank you! Can you please explain me why it needs a default constructor?

Comment: In C++11 we can also do `Player() = default;`

Answer (score 0):

Your class `Node` should have a constructor which take a `T` so you can construct your T by copy instead of requiring to have a default constructor and copy.

your Node class would be something like:

```
template <class T>
class Node
{
public:
    Node(const T& data) : data(data), next(0) {}
    void setNextNull();
    void setNext(Node*);

    const T& getData() const { return data; }
    T& getData() { return data; }
    Node* getNext();

private:
    T data;
    Node* next;
};
```

and so you transform

```
head = new node_type;
head->setData(data);
```

by

```
head = new node_type(data);
```

Comment: I've just added a constructor but it gives me the same error!

Comment: Works like a charm but can you please provide further explaination about the constructor' syntax?